# In how many different ways can we declare a main method in java?

Tags: java

I how many different ways can we declare a main method in java?

```
class A{
    public static void main(String args[]){
       System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

Now I want different ways to create a main method. Could you explain me?

Comment: An almost infinite number of ways, since you can choose any name you want for the argument.  If you want a sensible answer, you will need to explain WHY you want to create the `main` method in different ways.

Answer (score 5):

```
public static void main(String[] argument)

public static void main(String argument[])

public static void main(String... args)

public static synchronized void main(String... args)

public static strictfp void main(String... args)

public static final void main(String... args)
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4) there are only two ways:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

and

```
public static void main(String... args)
```

Answer (score 3):

The multiple ways of declaring the main method is (As everyone explained above)

1. **public static void main(String[] args) or public static void main(String args[])**
2. **public static void main(String... args).** 
   The positions of public and static may change as the programmer wish. But remember void should always come before main method. You can also use any parameters for the main method but the main with **String[] args** will only be executed first.
   You can also execute a java program without a main method. For this you need to make use of static block with a break statement at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the methods below. Which ones will not compile? Which ones will compile, but can’t be used as entry points into an application? Which ones compile and act as you would expect a main method to act?

if any doubts in this regard please verify the following link

http://rationalpi.wordpress.com/2007/01/29/main-method...

Answer (score 1):

you can also do this

```
static public void main(String args[])
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways
*By using single argument*

```
public static void main(String args) { .. }
```

*Or by varargs*

```
public static void main(String... args) { .. }
```

Keep in mind that `args` in `(String args)` is just a argument name.You can use anything here like `(String abc)` , `(String myargs)` etc.
One last thing is that ,you can also pass a multi dimensional array from main like this

```
public static void main(String[][] args) { .. }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use var-args instead of array:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Also this

```
public static void main(String... args)
```